# Не срабатывает условие if при сравнивании char

Tags: c++, if, char

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    char str1[32];
    char str2[32];
    Node *r, *l;
};

void show(Node *&Tree)
{
    if (Tree != NULL)
    {
        show(Tree->l);
        cout << Tree->str1<<" "<<Tree->str2<<endl;
        show(Tree->r);
    }
}

void addNode(char* x,char* y,Node *&MyTree)
{
    if (NULL==MyTree)
    {
        MyTree = new Node;

        strcpy_s(MyTree->str1, x);
        strcpy_s(MyTree->str2, y);
        MyTree->l = MyTree->r = NULL;
    }
    if (MyTree != NULL){


        int k = strcmp(x, MyTree->str1);

        if (k < 0)
        {
            if (MyTree->l != NULL) addNode(x, y, MyTree->l);
            else
            {
                MyTree->l = new Node;
                MyTree->l->l = MyTree->l->r = NULL;
                strcpy_s(MyTree->l->str1, x);
                strcpy_s(MyTree->l->str2, y);

            }
        }

        if (k > 0)
        {
            if (MyTree->r != NULL) addNode(x, y, MyTree->r);
            else
            {
                MyTree->r = new Node;
                MyTree->r->l = MyTree->r->r = NULL;
                strcpy_s(MyTree->r->str1, x);
                strcpy_s(MyTree->r->str2, y);

            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *Tree = NULL;
    char x[32];
    char y[32];

    while (x != "yyy")
    {
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        if (x == "yyy")break;
        addNode(x, y, Tree);
    }

    show(Tree);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В этом месте при вводе "yyy" if не срабатывает. Цикл дальше проходит

```
while (x != "yyy")
        {
            cin >> x;
            cin >> y;
            if (x == "yyy")break;
            addNode(x, y, Tree);
        }
```

Comment: У вас в коде уже правильно используется `strcmp`. Почему вдруг в условии `while` вы ни с того ни сего использовали `!=`?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно memcmp ?

```
const char tag[] = "yyy";

    while (1)
    {
        cin >> x;
        if (!memcmp((void*)x, (void*)tag, (sizeof(tag) - 1))) { break; }
        cin >> y;
        addNode(x, y, Tree);
    }
```

вот [рабочий пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b5533c82312cd86) вашего кода.
Часть с ручным вводом закоментирована, иначе при загрузке подвисает из за его отсутствия.
Вместо него добавлен автоматический тестовый цикл.